# join 3 tables and select count

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, count, join

i have 3 tables {websites} {accounts} {ads}

websites table

```
id     title    url           etc
-----------------------------------
1      site1    site1.com     ...
2      site2    site1.com     ...
3      site3    site3.com     ...
```

accounts table

```
id     websiteID   username    etc
-----------------------------------
1      1           username1   ...
2      2           username2   ...
3      1           username1   ...
4      3           username5   ...
```

ads table

```
id     accountID   title    etc
---------------------------------
1      1           title1   ...
2      2           title1   ...
3      1           title3   ...
5      4           title4   ...
```

i want to join these 3 table start from website table and get some data from website table , and **accounts_count** ralated to its website , and **ads_count** related to its account . also i want zero or null result for counts. 
usernames inside account table are not unique and can be same.
titles inside ads table are not unique too and can be same.

this is my query but some times it return wrong result on counts !

```
SELECT 
    websites.id as website_id
,   websites.title as website_title
,   COUNT(accounts.websiteID) as accounts_count
,   COUNT(ads.accountID) as ads_count
,   ads.lastUpdate
,   websites.activation as website_activation 
FROM websites 
LEFT JOIN accounts 
    ON websites.id = accounts.websiteID 
LEFT JOIN ads 
    ON accounts.id = ads.accountID
GROUP BY websites.id;
```

can u help me :{

i want show this result in a table like this:

```
website_title     accounts_count   ads_count    last update  operations
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
website1           3               8            2017/07/27   etc...
website2           0               0            2017/07/27   etc...
website3           3               9            2017/07/27   etc...
website4           5               15           2017/07/27   etc...
```

Comment: what is desired output

Comment: Add a sample out of the resultant expected

Comment: Looking at your select i do not know if you really know what you want. If your select contain `ads.lastUpdate` then what you really need to count and have in the result? Show desired output, you try to achieve

Comment: i added output i want to achieve

Comment: Can u please chk my answer, what i found with your query is you missed some fields in group by, when you apply aggregate function you should consider all columns except those are not aggregating

Comment: and what is `last update` here and from which of this adds it come from? Do you need `max(lastUpdate)`?

Comment: each ads can be updated and have a last update col , but my issue is counting accouts inside a website , and then counting all ads inside all acounts related to its own website . for exmple website1 has 3 account and inside each account can be some ads , i wanna accounts count and ads count related to its website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the counts need to change.
And a MAX for the ads.lastUpdate would be more accurate.

F.e.

```
SELECT 
    websites.id as website_id
,   websites.title as website_title
,   COUNT(DISTINCT accounts.ID) as accounts_count
,   COUNT(ads.ID) as ads_count
,   MAX(ads.lastUpdate) as LastUpdateAds
,   websites.activation as website_activation 
FROM websites 
LEFT JOIN accounts 
    ON websites.id = accounts.websiteID 
LEFT JOIN ads 
    ON accounts.id = ads.accountID
GROUP BY websites.id;
```

Comment: @AlirezaKafi Do note that the lastUpdate is also aggregated with a MAX in this version. And a `count(distinct value)` counts the unique values that are not null.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you join `websites` with accounts you get row for each row in `accounts`. Then when you join with `ads` you further multiplicate the row count. My guess is you now get same count for `accounts_count` and `ads_count`. Furthermore you have `lastUpdate` column from `ads` table and with agregate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT websites.id as website_id, websites.title as website_title,  
   ads.lastUpdate, websites.activation as website_activation 
   COUNT(accounts.websiteID) as accounts_count, COUNT(ads.accountID) as ads_count, 
FROM websites, accounts, ads
WHERE websites.id = accounts.websiteID 
   AND accounts.id = ads.accountID;
```